# Implementation of faster Fifo in SML

Tags: sml, mutable, smlnj

Can there be an implementation of Fifo, supporting a subset of its functions, namely just `Enqueue`, `Dequeue`, `isEmpty`, and the initialization `empty` with general `'a` objects, using some kind of mutable pointers, so that there will be no incurred cost of copying one list at certain times that the current two-list implementation uses (none when complexities are taken amortized, since it's still O(1) amortized cost of operations, but still inadequate for one of my applications) and if yes, how exactly?

Comment: Those look like the normal FIFO operations to me, rather than a subset.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use an [`Array`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/array.html) for a [dynamic array solution](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Queue/Definition#Dynamic_array), which would also incur an amortized cost, or you could implement [doubly-linked lists](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Queue/Definition#Doubly_linked_list) using the `ref` and `option` types. I've linked to the C solutions since such solutions are analogous although syntactically more complicated in SML, and because I couldn't find any examples in SML. The doubly-linked list solution will incur a memory overhead as each node is boxed, but will be free of the amortized cost of either the dynamic array solution or the fully functional deque that you describe.

Functional double-ended queues has been a topic of much research; there are some references in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue#Language_support) on several data structures and approaches both relying on laziness and not. I don't know that any of them are *O(1)*; it seems that they're all either *O(1)* amortized or *O(lg n)*, but still efficient.

Here's how the non-functional doubly-linked list data type might look like:

```
datatype 'a node = Node of { elem : 'a
                           , prev : 'a node option ref
                           , next : 'a node option ref
                           }

datatype 'a deque = Empty | NonEmpty of 'a node
```

There are some downsides to such an implementation:

- Keeping track of the references is not syntactically nice. In C you may write

  ```
  if (nd->prev) nd->prev->next = nd;
  ```

  but that looks a lot more obscure in SML unless you define a bunch of helper functions for getting and setting previous/next nodes. And even when you do that, since references are not commonly used, your getters and setters will look non-standard unlike C's pointer syntax.
- You're re-inventing null pointers. The implementation itself is fragile, since you may have cases where a previous/next node is a reference to `NONE` when it shouldn't be. The operations won't grow beyond push, pop, shift and unshift, so when you've made those, you can rely on testing (unit or property-based). You absolutely have to test this, I'd say, not buying into the strengths normally leveraged by ML.
- Your queue is mutable, so now you have to be careful with where you pass it along. If your use of the queue enters a broken state, you can't as easily find the source that caused it. You're basically coding C with uglier syntax.

So the short answer is: You can definitely write the same implementation, but the language does not encourage this, and functional programmers often rely on the immutable data structures with logarithmic or amortized running times.